# how to upload file to my web server via web site in C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I want to give upload option in my web page. i am using fileupload control. So i tried using the following code

```
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
  FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + filename ));
```

But that is not allowing me to up load. it fails while mapping the server.
Can any one tell me how i can upload file to the server via my web site.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: access denied. but i gave read and write permission to that folder.

Comment: Does your client have privileges to the folder? Have you tried uploading the data to the public folder(s)?

Comment: i published my website to the local wwwroot and tried to upload in the LAN it is coping the file to wwwroot. so i think its having.